# how to write spark context in java in spark 1.6.3 , so that to convert file into dataframe.

Tags: apache-spark

i have tried like this. but no luck.File1 and file2 are in my local machine. Not in the hdfs. Please help.

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("sample");
    SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf);
    SQLContext sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc);
    val file1=sc.textFile("file1.txt", minPartitions);
    val file2=sc.textFile("file2.txt", minPartitions);
```

Comment: If you are using Java, why is your code looks like Scala?

Comment: hi Nephilim, am unable to read the text file and convert into data frames in java, so was trying to use in this way, but no luck. I stuck in the middle

Comment: val file1=sc.textFile("file1.txt", minPartitions);--> at this point, am confused. Because my file is in local , so how to read it.

Comment: tried in java with javasparkcontext. but when trying to load the file getting error like "JavaRDD cannot be resolved to a type" at JavaRDD<String> input1 = sc.textFile("D:/File1.txt");

Comment: SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("App");
  JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
  JavaRDD<String> input1 = sc.textFile("D:/File1.txt");
  JavaRDD<String> input2 = sc.textFile("D:/File2.txt");

Comment: the error is resolved, I didn't gave import statement for javaRDD . Now I have given it.